# Using Pytorch to adjust Highlights and Shadows

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pytorch

Is there a way to adjust the image's highlights and shadows like in photoshop?
[image]

I have used `torchvision.transforms.functional` to adjust brightness and contrast. I want to know if they're a similar way to adjust highlights and shadows as well.